# XOR шифрование на СИ

Tags: c, шифрование, xor

В ходе xor шифрования символьного массива возможно получить такие символы, которые при дальнейшей записи в текстовый файл и чтения из него повредят структуру файла? Если да, то какие это символы, кроме \0?

Comment: Что значит "повредят структуру файла"? Будут нечитаемы глазами? :)

Comment: Файл может содержать абсолютно любые байты, в том числе и \0 тоже. Некоторые текстовые редакторы умеют его корректно обрабатывать.

Comment: Функция  fprintf в случае встречи, допустим, с \0 прекратит печать. Соответственно потеря данных, нет?

Comment: Никто не запрещает использовать какую-нибудь другую функцию, например fwrite